# Google Lighthouse Contrast Ratio - bad contrast ratio but it's not

Tags: seo, google-chrome, lighthouse

I have a site where chrome dev tools light house is saying stuff does not have a sufficient contrast ratio: Steps:

1. Go to https://curtainrodclub.net/product/architrac-94001-overlap-master-left/
2. Open Chrome dev tools.
3. Run lighthouse
   [image]
4. Click on one of the elements (h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title)
   5)Inspect color css
   [image]
   6)The contrast ratio meets all of google requirements so why is googles SEO tool saying it has bad contrast ratio. I have tried taking all h1 styles and applying them to h2 styles but that did not work.

Comment: It's a piece of software, and as such it's sometimes buggy. If your users are okay with it, and you are, and manually checking it shows it's ok - you are pretty much in  the clear (in my opinion).

Comment: I guess I am trying to get it to 100% for google search rankings in new SEO stats

Answer (score 3):

I have a few guesses that I hope will help you solve the problem

1. Clickable targets are at least 44 by 44 pixels in size unless an alternative target of that size is provided, the target is inline ([such as a link within a sentence](https://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist#sc2.5.5)), the target is not author-modified (such as a default checkbox), or the small target size is essential to the functionality.

[image]

2. DevTools [provides auto color suggestion](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-86#accessible-color) to help you fix the low contrast text.
3. **Color and contrast accessibility [said](https://web.dev/color-and-contrast-accessibility/):**
   "For a more complete report, install the [Accessibility Insights Extension](https://accessibilityinsights.io/). One of the checks in the Fastpass report, is color contrast. You will get a detailed report of any failing elements".

Answer (score 2):

It's the light-gray #222 that you have set in WooCommerce. Change it to something darker. Like black.

Also, since you are running WordPress/WooCommerce, try the [wa11y plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wa11y/) to test for accessibility.